# What's the mode of a function?

Tags: statistics

Probability concepts work both on samples and populations.

The mean of a probability distribution is:

$$ \text{Population Mean}[y] = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} y\rho(y) \, \mathrm{d} y $$

The mean of a sample is:

$$ \text{Sample Mean}[y] = \sum y_i/n $$

A discrete sample of values from a probability distribution can be viewed as a partial function from natural numbers to sampled values. The concept can then be extended to continuous samples as partial functions from real numbers to values.

The mean of a function is then:

$$ \text{Mean}[y] = \frac{\Delta \int y \, \mathrm{d} x}{\Delta x} $$

The root mean square of a function is:

$$ \text{RMS}[y] = \sqrt{\frac{\Delta \int y^2 \, \mathrm{d} x}{\Delta x}} $$

The median of a function is:

$$  \text{Median}[y] = y_m \leftarrow \int^m_a y \, \mathrm{d} x = \int^b_m y \, \mathrm{d} x $$

The population mode is the value that maximizes the probability density function.

What's the mode or most common value of a function?

Given a probability density $\rho(y)$ and an "infinite" number of samples $y$ what best predicts the maximum of $\rho(y)$ from $y$?

Answer (score 1):

**Comments:**

There is no guarantee that a density function (PDF) of a continuous distribution will have a (unique) mode. For example, the uniform distribution on $(0, 1)$ has no mode. A 50-50 mixture of two normal distributions $Norm(\mu_1, \sigma)$ and
$Norm(\mu_, \sigma)$ will have a double mode provided that the $\mu_i$ are
separated by several standard deviations. If the density function is continuous and differentiable, then normal methods of calculus can be used to find the location of the maximum.

If you have data and are trying to estimate the position of the mode of the
population from which they were sampled, then a traditional method is to
make a histogram, and use the center of the tallest bar as a rough estimate.
However, histograms with different choices of bins may give somewhat different answers. A more modern method of estimating a density (and hence its mode, if
one exists) is called 'kernel density estimation' (see Wikipedia, etc.)

Below is an example (green curve) of such a density estimator as implemented
in R statistical software. In the population, the two 'modes' are of equal
height, but in the sample the 'mode' nearest 115 predominates slightly.
The population is a 50-50 mixture of $Norm(85, 10)$ and $Norm(115, 10)$
The histogram is based on a sample of size 2000.

[image]

Note: A famous natural example of bimodal data is a much-quoted dataset of
waiting times between eruptions of Old Faithful geyser in Yellowstone
National park. [Weisberg (1985) Linear regression, Wiley]